# Assign a Protected Variable to a ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a protected variable called "fname" < and I have a arraylist where I have a scanner and whatever the user inputs, gets assigned to the arraylist. What I am hoping to do is, whatever the user inputs, gets assigned to the variable "fname". What I have so far is this: (it's protected because I am using it in another derived class)

```
protected String fname;
```

The arraylist:

```
Scanner FN = new Scanner(System.in);
ArrayList<String>fname = new ArrayList<String>();
{
   System.out.println("Enter your firstname: ");
   fname.add(FN.next());
}
```

Comment: I've read it twice and didn't understand the problem

Comment: I don't understand your question. But why are you shadowing the protected variable `fname`?

Comment: You didn't ask a question. What are you having issues with?

Comment: May be he thinks that SO is some kind of micro-blog where people post here current thoughts and troubles?

Comment: fname is declared twice, as String, and ArrayList<String>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need an Array List to do that.

The Declaration:

```
protected String fname = null;
```

The Input reading:

```
Scanner FN = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter your firstname: ");
fname = FN.next();
```

Comment: I have two other classes that use the information from the abstract class to get information, but also add additional information depending on whether the class is called. How would i use a if Function in the main class to call the pubic void?

StudentInfo.java
public abstract class StudentInfo
{
  Protected String fname = null;
}


public void setapp()
        {
           Scanner AN = new Scanner(System.in);
           System.out.println("Enter your Full Name: ");
           appName = AN.next();
        }

@MarkusKnecht

Comment: @Kyle02: I do not exactly understand what your setup is.
Do these other classes extend StudentInfo or are these completely different classes. and what do you mean with wether the class is called. classes cant be called, they can be instantiated or do you mean when a methode on the class is called in this case which method?